# Android MediaPlayer won't play raw MP3 resource

Tags: android

I have read many posts about how to play an MP3 raw resource in Android program. It seems to be simple, just two lines of code, but it won't work on my ZTE Blade III which I'm using for development. What makes it weird is that it actually works on my tablet. I can hear the sound on the tablet, but not on the phone, using the same APK. This is my code:

```
private MediaPlayer mpClick;
...
mpClick = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.click);
mpClick.start();
```

The program actually doesn't throw an exception on the phone, instead it just doesn't play the sound, and also I see these three lines in the console each time:

```
E/wlg(7087): MediaPlayer.start()  mIsStream = false
D/MediaPlayer(7087): start() mUri is null
E/MediaPlayer(7087): start() mDrmFileHandle = 0, mstartUsage = true
```

Could something be wrong with the phone (because it works with my tablet), or there is something that I can change in my code?